# ¿Como hago las opciones de un Modal Dropdown mas angostas ? (React Native)

Tags: reactjs, react-native, modal, dropdown

[image: texto en negrita]

Basicamente quisiera que el espacio entre cada opción sea mas ancho, ya que es difícil picarle a cada uno estando en un celular.
He tratado con margin y padding y ninguno me da resultado

```
<ModalDropdown
            options={days}
            onSelect={(v) => setDay(v + 1)}
            defaultValue={day || '    Día ▾'}
            style={styles.dropdown}
            textStyle={styles.dropdownText}
            dropdownStyle={{
              width: 67,
              backgroundColor: 'rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.07)',
              borderColor:'#fff',
              borderWidth:3, alignItems:'stretch'
            }}
          />

dropdown: {
backgroundColor: 'rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.07)',
width: 87,
height: 38,
paddingTop: 6,
borderRadius: 10,
borderWidth:3,
borderColor:'#fff',
paddingVertical:5,
justifyContent:'center'


  dropdownText: {
    textAlign: 'center',
    opacity: 1,
    color:'#fff',
    fontSize: 16
  },
```

No se muy bien si estoy agregando el padding y el margin en los estilos correctos pero simplemente no logro hacerlos mas anchos

Answer (score 0):

En mi opinión, sería mejor usar estilos CSS

```
@media screen (max-width: 786px) {
 Para móvil {margin: 10px auto}
};
```